# Zklibrary doesn't connect with ZKTEco Biometric Attendance connection Password

Tags: php, zkteco

I've created a PHP script to get the data from the attendance machines. the main library I found in StackOverflow and GitHub is zklibrary for ZKTeco Biometric attendance machines.

The Scripts are working very well without the communication key. I want to create the connection including the device connection key. after over searching most topics were advised to clear the password.

Could anyone please have any method to make the connection without clearing the password?

Biometric Model : ZKTeco 14

ZKLibrary :https://github.com/kamshory/ZKLibrary

Best Regards